# Problem with saving excel file after first app exit

Tags: python, openpyxl

Today I was working on an application that adds tarantula species to my Excel document. Now I'm trying to implement exiting from the app by input from which I'm taking Yes or No, and if the user answers yes, the application closes. But when I'm closing after adding only one tarantula, my file is not saving. Here is the code that exits the application (I'm not getting any errors):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side
import random
import time
import keyboard
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx") 

ws = wb.active
while True:
    def InsertTarantula (genus, species, borderBottom):

        mediumBorder = Border(left=Side(style='none'), 
                        right=Side(style='none'), 
                        top=Side(style='none'), 
                        bottom=Side(style='thin'))

        for row in range(1, ws.max_row+2):
            if ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value == None and ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value == None:
                #print(ws.cell(row=row, column=1).coordinate, ws.cell(row=row, column=2).coordinate)
                ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value = genus
                ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = species
                if (borderBottom == True):
                    ws.cell(row=row, column=1).border = mediumBorder
                    ws.cell(row=row, column=2).border = mediumBorder
                break

    genus = input("Enter tarantula genus: ")
    species = input("Enter tarantula species: ")
    addTo = input("Do you want to add this tarantula to excel sheet? [Y/N]: ")
    addBottomBorder = input("Do you want to add bottom border to your last tarantula? [Y/N]: ")
    exitApp = input("Do you want to exit app? [Y/N]: ")

    #genus = "Brachypelma"
    #species = "Yaxchilan"
    #addTo = "Y"
    #addBottomBorder = "Y"
    #exitApp = "N"

    #########Check if user wants to put tarantula to sheet###########################
    if (addTo.isupper() == True and addBottomBorder == False):
        if (addTo == "Y"):
            InsertTarantula(genus, species, False)
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
        elif (addTo == "N"):
            pass
    elif (addTo.isupper() == False and addBottomBorder == False):
        if (addTo == "y"):
            InsertTarantula(genus, species, False)
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
        elif (addTo == "n"):
            pass

    ##################Check if user wants to exit application#######################
    if (exitApp.isupper() == True):
        if (exitApp == "Y"):
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
            exit()
        elif (exitApp == "N"):
            pass
    elif (exitApp.isupper() == False):
        if (exitApp == "y"):
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
            exit()
        elif (exitApp == "n"):
            pass

    #################Check if user wants to add bottom border to cell######################
    if (addBottomBorder.isupper() == True):
        if (addBottomBorder == "Y"):
            InsertTarantula(genus, species, True)
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
        elif (addBottomBorder == "N"):
            pass
    elif (addBottomBorder.isupper() == False):
        if (addBottomBorder == "y"):
            InsertTarantula(genus, species, True)
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
        elif (addBottomBorder == "n"):
            pass



wb.save("sample.xlsx")

input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Comment: Giving more of your application's code would be helpful

Comment: The code you supplied seems to be ok, I see no problem there. Please tell us how you "add only one tarantula".
Additionally, your code could be simplificated a little: Use `exitApp.upper()` (or `.lower`), so it will contain only the upper or lower case version and you can avoid the "outer" if statement. (E. g.: `if (exitApp.upper() == "Y"): #... elif (exitApp.upper() == "N"): #...` - no more need to check for `y` or `n`).

Comment: ok i updated here is the whole code. And btw by only one tarantula i meant that i write its name then i choose yes for adding to sheet and yes for closing application

Comment: The problem might be in the first block: What if addTo is `Y` or `y`, but `addBottomBorder` is `True`? Anyway, `addBottomBorder` is a string and should therefore be compared to y/Y/n/N as well.
Suggestion: First, get booleans out of `addTo`, `addBottomBorder` and `exitApp` (possibly using the way I described in my last comment), THEN just evaluate these booleans to find out what to do.

Comment: that really helped so thank you. I used kinda different aproach but very similiar